# Add & execute package to Defrag a fragmented Ext3 Volume under BusyBox in Synology CS407? How?

Tags: busybox, fsck, e2fsck, synology, defragmentation

Add & execute package to Defrag a fragmented Ext3 Volume under BusyBox in Synology CS407? How?

---

**Note:** **Debunking the myth of Linux Filesystems not getting fragmented.** 
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/install-defrag-defragmentation.html

> But that's a common misconception and **in some cases you do have to defragment your Linux filesystems**. This is even [**confirmed by an Ubuntu developer on a very recent post**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1434502) I stumbled upon just a few minutes ago about ureadahead on the ubuntuforums.

**From:** Ubuntu Forums Post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1434502

> The only way to avoid this is defragmenting your disk.

**But Linux filesystems don't need defragmenting!**

**Whoever told you that is deeply mistaken, this is one of the most common myths of Linux.**

What is true is that **Linux filesystems avoid, where possible, fragmenting their inode tables**. This means that the index of how files are split up (fragmented) across the disk, and where those parts are, tends to be kept together as a whole.

That's a good thing; fragmentation of inode tables is a big problem for other filesystems (FATs in that filesystem, etc.) so by keeping them together, it wins a lot of performance.

But the **data itself is still fragmented**, and **spread all over your disk in a random order**. And unfortunately during boot, it's the data we need.

One of the future things we want to do is use the ureadahead analysis of what we need during boot to feed into a defragmenter, so everything we need is in one big block on the disk.

---

**Update:**

> Apparently, the CS407 uses a Marvel processer 88f5281 so it might need something like a specially built optware/ entware first. Please, do guide more in this direction if possible.

http://www.nas-central.org/w/index.php?title=Collection_of_NAS-Hacking_communities#Marvell_Orion-1.2FOrion-NAS.2FOrion-2_based_NAS_devices

---

https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=66550
https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=83186#p339475
**Based on the steps & lessons in these 2 links I ran the following (key stuff marked & bolded with double Asterix):**

**Busybox Version:**
`BusyBox v1.16.1 (2011-04-08 10:15:04 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.`

**Commandline Input & Output:**
`CubeStation> /usr/syno/etc.defaults/rc.d/S80samba.sh stop
CubeStation> df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               2451064    478484   1870180  20% /
/tmp                     63396       288     63108   0% /tmp
/dev/md2             2879637816 2336710312 542825104  81% /volume1
CubeStation> unmount /volume1
-ash: unmount: not found
CubeStation> sudo unmount /volume1
-ash: sudo: not found
CubeStation> syno_poweroff_task
CubeStation> df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               2451064    478460   1870204  20% /
/tmp                     63396       284     63112   0% /tmp
CubeStation> vgdisplay
CubeStation> e2fsck -v -n -f /dev/md2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
/lost+found not found.  Create? no
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
1.41.12-1613: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
   42150 inodes used (0.02%)
    3618 non-contiguous files (8.6%)
      20 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
         # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 20326/8705/71
595654428 blocks used (81.44%)
       0 bad blocks
     114 large files
   36634 regular files
    4434 directories
       0 character device files
       0 block device files
       0 fifos
       1 link
    1073 symbolic links (1073 fast symbolic links)
       0 sockets`

- I am not a *Nix expert, but have a CS & IT background and am fine with running stuff on the command line. I've read a lot but just wish to piece together the right compatible packages/ components (for this system) & steps here.

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/21142/is-there-a-ext3-defragmenter
  - http://www.webupd8.org/2009/10/defragmenting-linux-ext3-filesystems.html
  - http://vleu.net/shake/
- I am guessing this may be lacking some packages/ components that will provide me with the ability to run a Defrag.
- Should I/ Can I install them (the ones linked above)?  Which ones & how?
- How best to execute them?

**What can I do to DEFRAG the volume FS & the non-contiguous data?**

Comment: One thing I immediately noticed, you typed `unmount` which is incorrect, should be `umount`. Also fragmented files are not an issue/error, it simply means that if you're using a magnetic rotating hard disk, the system have to make a few extra disk seeks to the hard disk to piece together your files, this is handled automatically by the system, and it's quite normal to have them.

Comment: @LieRyan - Yes, honest mistake. I know what fragmentation is, and I'd like to once in a while do a defrag (which I know most *nix people say is not needed). I'd like to defrag my NAS - How can I add & execute one of the defrag tools in the *nix space? (few linked above)

Comment: The old-school method - before defragmentation software in any OS - was simply to move the files to another location, format the original partition/volume, and then move them back. You might even skip the formatting portion.

Answer (score 0):

When running commands from the internet, it's always a good idea to cross check what the commands does with the manual page.

In your specific case, your e2fsck command:

```
e2fsck -v -n -f /dev/md2
```

If we check what this commands does in the [e2fsck man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/e2fsck8.html) you'll see:

> **-n  Open the filesystem read-only, and assume an answer of ‘no’ to all questions**. Allows e2fsck to be used non-interactively. (Note: if the -c, -l, or -L options are specified in addition to the -n option, then the filesystem will be opened read-write, to permit the bad-blocks list to be updated. However, no other changes will be made to the filesystem.)

So what the -n flag does is to do a disk check without repairing any issues it found. You'd want to remove this flag to let it repair issues. You'll get prompts for each issue e2fsck found and try to repairs. If you want e2fsck to just repair everything without prompts, add -p flag:

> -p Automatically repair ("preen") the file system without any questions.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response. I am already aware of the -n making it "read only" as that was the initial objective to check it for fragmentation  - which people say Linux Ext systems never have. 
I can run it again without the Read flag, but how do I defrag it?

Comment: How can I add & execute one of the defrag tools in the *nix space? PS: Please add this part as that is the key part of question that I cant resolve

Comment: @AlexS: ext2 filesystem can have fragmentation, but [it does not need defragmentation](https://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:EXT2_Fragmentation). I can give you scripts/commands to run that means you feel good, if that's what you want, but they won't do any good for the system. Your e2fsck result does not indicate that you need to do any defragmentation. Linux disk allocators and IO scheduler prevents problematic disk fragmentations from forming and makes use of fragmentations to improve throughput.

Comment: Most of the stuff on my NAS is media (mostly read only to watch, except when I am uploading new collections to it). I'd like to keep the media as contiguous as possible. I'd really appreciate if you can help me add the right defrag package & execute it on this "limited" BusyBox Linux. 
PS: I get the throughput v/s contiguous thing - I'd like to make it contiguous. Thanks. Please guide.

Comment: @AlexS: I can point you to a Synology's documentation on how to set up cross compiler and build a custom package for your device. But given your lack of basic knowledge about Linux systems maintenance, you are more likely to get into trouble and lose data than any issue you might think you could "fix" by defragging. Note that all existing ext2 defrag software are abandonware, you are **very likely to lose data by running a defrag software**. They're effectively abandoned experiments because people don't find them doing any better than just "sleep 3h; echo 'defragmentation complete'".

Comment: Are you saying no such package exists at the moment? Ok, Please do so. I do have a programming background so will give it a shot. On a side note, what if I pulled the HDD and attached it to my PC, booted into a Live Linux ISO and then ran a defrag with a better "utility/ tool/ app" that you'd recommend? 
Why bother? - The 3TB drive now has 600G free and I'd like to do it once before I fill it to the final level after which I pop in another HDD and this will be largely read only, if and until I start deleting things from it.

Comment: [Click here](https://developer.synology.com/developer-guide/index.html) if you want to waste a couple weekends and consider your data disposable enough to let a tool with proven zero usefulness wreck it. [Synology does not recommend defragging their own product](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/Is_it_necessary_to_defragment_the_internal_hard_drive_of_the_Synology_Product). I still recommend my script above, would do just as well with no risk of data loss: `sleep 3h; echo 'defragmentation complete'`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that due to ext's space allocation strategy, files get fragmented even easier as your disk fill up. Defragging now will not significantly reduce the amount of fragmentation that will happen as the disk gets filled to 100%. And no, this low space fragmentations aren't going to cause performance issue either.

Comment: I've read & seen that link already. Gone through the forums. I get everything you're saying, but I wish to run a Defrag atleast once on this disk/ volume and see - seeing is believing. So, if synology BusyBox build is not safe, I'd like to pull it to my PC and run a Defrag (via Mint Linux or Ubuntu) from there. It'd be great if you can point to the preferred Stable Defrag Linux tool that can work on Ext3 FS

Comment: @AlexS: if my message is not clear enough, all defrag tools are snake oil. You can pick whichever tool you want to trash the system, none you pick are going to make any bit of improvements. The `sleep 3h; echo 'defragmentation complete'` is the only tool I can responsibly recommend, as all the other has a chance of data loss and aren't going to be any more effective.